# How to make authenticated Cognito request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I can successfully run `describeIdentityPool` command for the Cognito Identity Pool with "Enable access to unauthenticated identities" enabled:

```
 var AWS = require("aws-sdk"); 
 let cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

  var params = {IdentityPoolId: "myIdentityPoolID"}; 

  cognitoidentity.describeIdentityPool(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); 
    }
    else {
      console.log( "...getCredentials.describeIdentityPool.data:", data); 
    }
  });
```

But if I disable the "Enable access to unauthenticated identities" check box I get the error:

```
NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.
```

Is there a way to authorize the request I make to Cognito Identity Pool to avoid this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's completely expected. Almost all APIs on AWS require an access key id and a secret access key. The `describeIdentityPool` API is one of them.

If you enable access for unauthenticated users they receive temporary credentials that allow them to perform that action. One of the actions allowed by default is `cognito-identity:*`. This is the one that allows unauthenticated users to call this API. You will be able to find it in a role assigned to the "Unauthenticated identities" setting.

When you disable unauthenticated entities they no longer receive temporary credentials and are therefore unable to call that API.

Long story short: Works as expected.